# Json string value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a Arduino that create a json string:

> {"sensorId":"[id sensore]","value":"[valore_letto_dal_sensore]"}

With this Arduino code:

```
    client.println("POST *file PHP  * HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: *URL web site*");
    client.println("Accept: */" "*");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0.0");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(post.length());
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.print(post);

    post = "";
```

So with POST send to file .PHP name of sensor and value.
Can you help me to create db and PHP file?

I find a web site that create a chart with goole api http://blog.mikinacucchi.it/2013/08/rilevazione-temperatura-arduino-php-json-googlechart/

Comment: You should look up what [the right way to create a PHP application with a database](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension) is, and have a go at making a simple script. If you have specific problems you can ask on here.

Comment: sorry but i see code but i am  able to do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

i find it....I create a db with table with 2 column :1° idsensor, 2° value of sensor.
i create 3 files:

connect.php:

```
<?php

    function Connection(){
    $server="server";
    $user="user";
    $pass="pass";
    $db="database";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);

    if (!$connection) {
        die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db($db) or die( 'MySQL ERROR: '. mysql_error() );

    return $connection;
}
?>
```

add.php:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$link=Connection();

$sensorId=$_POST["sensorId"];
$value=$_POST["value"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `Log` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
    VALUES ('".$sensorId."','".$value."')"; 

mysql_query($query,$link);
mysql_close($link);


?>
```

index.php:

```
 <?php

    include("connect.php");     

    $link=Connection();

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Log` ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC",$link);
    ?>

<html>
```

```
<?php

    include("connect.php");     

    $link=Connection();

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempLog

` ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC",$link);
    ?>

    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Sensor Data</title>
       </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Temperature / moisture sensor readings</h1>

       <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;Temperature 1&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;Moisture 1&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

          <?php 
              if($result!==FALSE){
                 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
                       $row["timeStamp"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"]);
                 }
                 mysql_free_result($result);
                 mysql_close();
              }
          ?>

       </table>
    </body>
    </html>



     <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;Sensor;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;value;</td>


            </tr>

      <?php 
          if($result!==FALSE){
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
                   $row["timeStamp"], $row["sensorId"], $row["value"]);
             }
             mysql_free_result($result);
             mysql_close();
          }
      ?>

   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can say me if all is ok???

Comment: Best to add this code to your initial question. You should read over the link I posted on [how to do databases with PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension) - the way you're doing this is using an old unsupported library which lacks features and is not secure. You'll help yourself by using `PDO` to create a connection and working with that to store your data.